# Verbs for seesaw

Tags: verbs

There are usually seesaws at playgrounds in parks. Many kids love to play on them. As an ESL learner, I'd like to know which verbs go with the noun "seesaw" in following scenarios:

1. There is a seesaw over there. Let's (B1) it.
2. (B2) the seesaw.  It's going to break.
3. (B3) the seesaw. I can't play by myself.

B1: might be "play on/play/ride on"?
B2: "Get off"?
B3: "Get on"?

Comment: Did you swap B2 and B3 by mistake?

Comment: yes. should be:B2: "Get off"? B3:"Get on"?

Answer (score 1):

You ***play on*** a seesaw. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seesaw) describes the noun as...

> *A seesaw is a long board which is balanced on a fixed part in the middle. **To play on it,** a child sits on each end, and when one end goes up, the other goes down.*

So, the answers are:

> There's a seesaw over there [sic]. Let's *play on it!*

You have swapped the B2 and B3. And, your choices are fine.

> Get off the seesaw; it's going to break 
>  Get on *to* the seesaw; I can't play by myself.

[Somehow I feel that *'get on to'* is better]